# Delete certain rows in pandas dataframe with specific datetime value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I am just interested in the values which occur for the full hour. That is how my data looks like:

```
0     2016-01-01 00:00:00  11.263
1     2016-01-01 00:15:00  11.244
2     2016-01-01 00:30:00  11.109
3     2016-01-01 00:45:00  10.975
4     2016-01-01 01:00:00  10.849
```

The dataframe has about 50 000 rows. What I want it to look like:

```
0     2016-01-01 00:00:00  11.263
4     2016-01-01 01:00:00  10.849
```

I just want to see the values at full hours (1 am 2 am). Is there any possibility to do that? I have been trying out some stuff but it was not really working out. I have to admit that I am quite new to python.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with comparing column `date` with truncated values by [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

mask = df['date'] == df['date'].dt.floor('H')
df = df[mask]
print (df)
                 date     val
0 2016-01-01 00:00:00  11.263
4 2016-01-01 01:00:00  10.849
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thanks a lot worked out great! :)